# React Native Developer Menu sometimes doesn't show live reload option

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The title says it all. Sometimes I have access to all the buttons like here.

[image]

Other times, I have a limited set of options available.

[image]

Why do the options change from time to time although I run the project the same way and how do debug/fix it so all options are available?

Comment: Please share the relevant code otherwise it’s not much helpfull

Comment: I would show code but I have no idea of what code to show. I feel like this has to be a configuration problem with my project/xcode. The React Native Developer menu is available in any React Native project so I don't think this is a sourcecode issue?